# How to get the user data of a facebook group post? The original poster

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have gotten a post object from the Facebook Graph API as such:

```
GET/v2.5/142679255268_10153887281355269
```

Which returns an object like so:

```
{
  "created_time": "2016-03-25T03:28:50+0000",
  "message": "Whats up everybody, I am here now",
  "id": "142679255268_10153887281355269"
}
```

How can I get the profile of the user who posted this?
I have looked through the documentation and couldnt find anything, but I know its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work for the Post item:

```
/142679255268_10153887281355269?fields=from
```

It returns the following JSON:

```
{
  "from": {
    "name": "Bhumi Patel",
    "id": "10153245821277822"
  },
  "id": "142679255268_10153887281355269"
}
```

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post/

**Edit: For data privacy reasons, you may not get the name of the user anymore.**

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, now I know how to access any field :)

Comment: As of v3 of the Facebook API, this does not seem to work anymore; does anyone know how to do this in the newer version?

Comment: i assume that it is not possible anymore because of data privacy reason.